# WGet Github Action

Tags: github-actions, flyway

I'm trying to install the Flyway CLI inside of my GitHub Action, however, I'm not able to find the package after the installation.

My expectation is for a folder `flyway-9.21.1` to be in my current directory, which I can then use to do flyway stuff.

If I do an `ls` on the current directory after the installation, the folder isn't there.

```
>Run ls ./
README.md
flyway.toml
migrations
```

Which results in the following error:

> flyway-9.21.1/flyway: No such file or directory

I have been using the [ACT](https://github.com/nektos/act) tool to run the action locally and the folder is present.

```
[Development deploy/Re-build] ⭐ Run Main LS
[Development deploy/Re-build]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/4] user= workdir=
| README.md  flyway-9.21.1  flyway.toml  migrations
```

I have also tried referring to the tool in the following ways:

- flyway-9.21.1/flyway
- ./flyway-9.21.1/flyway
- flyway

Based on this [example](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3023), it would appear that what I have done should work. I'd like to avoid using any other tools, i.e. Docker or 3rd party other actions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Full action:

```
name: "Development deploy"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development

env:
  SQLFLUFF_DIALECT: postgres
  DOCKER_IMAGE: redgate/flyway
  SCHEMAS: etslips

jobs:
  Re-build:
    name: Re-build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: "11"
          distribution: "temurin"

      - name: Download and Install Flyway CLI
        run: wget -qO- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/9.21.1/flyway-commandline-9.21.1-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar -xvz && ln -s `pwd`/flyway-9.21.1/flyway /usr/local/bin

      - name: Set Flyway Path
        run: PATH=/flyway:$PATH

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.0
      
      - name: LS
        run: ls ./

      - name: Clean
        run: flyway-9.21.1/flyway clean -url="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_URL }}" -user="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_USERNAME}}" -password="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_PASSWORD}}" -schemas="${{ env.SCHEMAS }}" -cleanDisabled=false

      - name: Migrate
        run: flyway migrate -url="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_URL }}" -user="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_USERNAME}}" -password="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_PASSWORD}}" -schemas="${{ env.SCHEMAS }}" -outOfOrder=false

      - name: Info
        run: flyway info -url="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_URL }}" -user="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_USERNAME}}" -password="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_PASSWORD}}" -schemas="${{ env.SCHEMAS }}" -outOfOrder=false

  Development-deploy:
    name: Development deployment
    needs: Re-build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.0

      - name: Info
        run: flyway info -url="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_URL }}" -user="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_USERNAME}}" -password="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_PASSWORD}}" -schemas="${{ env.SCHEMAS }}" -outOfOrder=false

      - name: Migrate
        run: flyway migrate -url="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_URL }}" -user="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_USERNAME}}" -password="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_PASSWORD}}" -schemas="${{ env.SCHEMAS }}" -outOfOrder=false

      - name: Info
        run: flyway info -url="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_URL }}" -user="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_USERNAME}}" -password="${{ secrets.DB_DEV_PASSWORD}}" -schemas="${{ env.SCHEMAS }}" -outOfOrder=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If I move the `ls` step above the `check out` step, you can see the tool present in the directory.

```
Run ls ./
flyway-9.21.1
```

I can only assume that the `check out` step was overwriting the directory and thus removing the tool. Moving the `checkout` step to the first in the action solved the issue.

```
      - name: Checkout # Moved to the top
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.0.0

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: "11"
          distribution: "temurin"

      - name: Download and Install Flyway CLI
        run: wget -qO- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/9.21.1/flyway-commandline-9.21.1-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar -xvz && ln -s `pwd`/flyway-9.21.1/flyway /usr/local/bin

      # Moved from here

      - name: Clean
        run: flyway clean -url="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_URL }}" -user="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_USERNAME}}" -password="${{ secrets.DB_BUILD_PASSWORD}}" -schemas="${{ env.SCHEMAS }}" -cleanDisabled=false

etc...
```